# How can I execute Scrapy in Django?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have a task that I have to scrape some websites with Scrapy. I also have to delete and edit some URLs with Django. I want to use Django 3.1 and Scrapy 2.3.0.

I already try Django-dynamic-scraper and Djangoitem. Because of some version problems, I couldn't use them.

There was a class to execute Django command's called call_command

```
call_command('Scrapy crawl ../first_bot/first_bot/spider.py', stdout=out)
```

But it is just for the Django command.

Is there any way to execute scrapy module when I click on a button on Django?

Comment: Have you considered using subprocess?

Comment: I tried it works fine but it works really slow I don't know why. Hammad's method work fine thank you so much. But I have mentioned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste code in python file start.py and Use this code in scrapy directory.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

# var = name of spider

process.crawl(var)
process.start()
```

In django run start.py using this code here ever you like

```
import platform
import os

if plt == "Windows":
    cwd = os.path.join("<path to file>", "start.py")
    os.system('{} {}'.format('python', cwd))

elif plt == "Linux":
    cwd = os.path.join("<path to file>", "start.py")
    os.system('{} {}'.format('python3', cwd))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I finish my task with your recommendation. But I have to mention that instead of **process.crawl(var)** I used **process.crawl(var.classname)** (the class have to import to)
 I think it is because python3